# MySQL Group By filter results by order

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with the following columns:

TblID - AUTO_INCREMENT
IndividualID
BranchID
TreeID

Only TblID is unique. I wish to query the table where TreeID = x and BranchID = y, to retrieve all the Individual records that share those characteristics. There could be many Individual records for one IndividualID, but I only want to retrieve the first one created (thus with the lowest TblID value) per IndividualID.

So I changed from:

```
SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE TreeID = :TreeID AND BranchID= :BranchID
```

To

```
SELECT * FROM `rep_options` WHERE TreeID = :TreeID AND BranchID= :BranchID
    GROUP BY IndividualID ORDER BY TblID ASC
```

This appears to be working, but I'm not comfortable enough with MySQL Groups to be confident that I'm getting to the right point by the right means.

Is this the right way to filter my returns to just one record per IndividualID, sorted by TblID?

Comment: Provided all the other values not being grouped by are identical, than this would work. However if any field such as TblID is important and not the same as all the other records returned, you may get undesirable results.

Comment: If you are looking to get the lowest/smallest `TblID` per `IndividualID`, then no, that won't do what you want. The `ORDER BY` will be applied _after_ the `GROUP BY`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need the lowest `TblID` value then use the `MIN` function, like this:

```
SELECT MIN(TblID) AS TblID, IndividualID, TreeID, BranchID
FROM `rep_options` 
WHERE TreeID = :TreeID AND BranchID= :BranchID
GROUP BY IndividualID 
ORDER BY TblID ASC
```

Ideally the `GROUP BY` clause should contain all the non-aggregated columns mentioned in the `SELECT` clause but it should not matter in this case because all rows will have same TreeID and BranchID values (due to the WHERE clause).

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT MIN(TblID) AS TblID, IndividualID, TreeID, BranchID
FROM `rep_options` 
WHERE TreeID = :TreeID AND BranchID= :BranchID
GROUP BY IndividualID, TreeId, BranchID
ORDER BY TblID ASC
```

I explicitly define the group bys for non-aggregate values.  It might be a bit more of a performance hit, but my results are less likely to be incorrect when the Group by extensions are enabled in MySQL (which they are by default)

IN this case since TreID and BrancID are in the where clause and you were already grouping by IndividualID it shouldn't matter... meaning you don't need  to have TreeID, branchID, but if one of the where clause criteria were later removed, it would matter.

Here's with a select * this may have a bit more ovehead but it should resolve the issue stemming from mySQLs extended Group by features.

The inner select gets the min ID and the individual.  This way the group by extensions no longer become an issue.

```
SELECT *
FROM `rep_options` a
INNER JOIN 
 (Select min(tblID) myID,  IndividualID
  FROM `rep_options` 
  WHERE TreeID = :TreeID AND BranchID= :BranchID
  group by IndividualID) b
  on a.Myid=a.tblID 
 and B.IndividualID = A.IndividualID
ORDER BY TblID ASC
```

Comment: Is there a way of doing this with a `SELECT *` statement? Or do I have to specify every column (there are many more besides the ones used for the question)?

Comment: @Eamonn if you have more columns then you will indeterminate results for them except the ones you have shown in your question both users answer is correct for your question but are invalid if you do have other columns ,you will see the minimum `TblID` but other columns results will be in indeterminate order these will not guarantee you to provide the first row for each group